# Limit question involving L'Hospitals rule

Tags: limits, probability-limit-theorems

I need help in solving the below question using L'Hospitals rule:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{1}{x^2}-\cot^2 x \right) $$

I'm getting infinity as the final answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is not "$\infty$." It can be done by L'Hospital's Rule, but series are far more natural and pleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{1}{x^2}-\cot^2 x \right) \\
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x} \right) \\
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2 \sin^2 x}-\frac{x^2 \cos^2 x}{x^2 \sin^2 x} \right) \\
= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left( \frac{\sin^2 x - x^2 \cos x}{x^2 \sin^2 x} \right) \\
$$
Now you have a fraction where both numerator and denominator approach $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, so you can invoke L'Hospital's rule by taking the derivative of both top and bottom.

Comment: Taking derivative on top and bottom is laborious in this case.

Comment: I agree with you!

Answer (score 3):

We use L'Hospital's Rule, although series are more natural.

Our function can be rewritten as 
$$\frac{1-x^2\cot^2 x}{x^2}.$$ Differentiate top and bottom. We get 
$$\frac{(-x^2)(2\cot x)(-\csc^2 x)-2x\cot^2 x}{2x},$$ 
which simplifies to $x\cot x\csc^2 x-\cot^2 x$.

Using the fact that $\cot x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$, we find that we want $$\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x\left(\frac{x}{\sin^3 x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2 x}\right).$$

The $\cos x$ part has limit $1$ as $x\to 0$. So we want
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x\cos x}{\sin^3 x}.$$

Use L'Hospital's Rule again. We want 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x}{3\sin^2 x\cos x}.$$
We could continue to use L'Hospital's Rule. However, that would be a waste of time. For the top is simply $2\sin^2 x$, so the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Don't you have to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}1-x^2\cot^2x=0$ before you can use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Yes, but it is obvious, since $\cot^2 x$ behaves like $x^2$ near $0$. (It is $\cos^2 x \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}$, and we know all about $\frac{x}{\sin x}$.)